# Create multiple table inside div dynamically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following JSON result and I need to bind it in the UI:

```
[
    {
        "name":"abc",
        "class" : "first"
    },
    {
        "name":"def",
        "class" : "first"
    }
],[
    {
        "name":"ijk",
        "class" : "second"
    },
    {
        "name":"lmn",
        "class" : "second"
    }
]
```

HTML:

```
<div id="itemListTable">
    <tbody id="invcdTlbBody" class="text-left">
    </tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
for(j=0;J<somelength;j++) {
    //create table header here
    var html = `"<table class='table' id='tab' width='100%' 
        style='margin-bottom: 0px;'><thead><th>NAME</th><th>CLASS</th></thead></table>";`
    $('#itemListTable').html(html); 


    for(i=0;i<somelength;j++){
        invcdTlbTr += '<tr>'
            + '<td width="20%">' + std.name + '</td>'
            + '<td width="35%">' + std.class + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';    
    }
    invcdTlbBody.innerHTML = invcdTlbBody.innerHTML
}
```

I get the following output:

**Name Class**

abc  first

def  first

ijk  second

lmn  second

but i need Following Output

**Name Class**

abc  first

def  first

**Name Class**

ijk  second

lmn  second

How do I repeat table header?

Comment: Your json is wrong as if it's an object ( {} ) it will be a **key/value** pair

Comment: @anura its an array of json i updated my question can you please look here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` to iterate through the array and `template string` (` `) to create a table for each outer array with **header** representing **Name** and **class**.

```js
var json = [[
    {
        "name":"abc",
        "class" : "first"
    },
    {
        "name":"def",
        "class" : "first"
    }
],[
    {
        "name":"ijk",
        "class" : "second"
    },
    {
        "name":"lmn",
        "class" : "second"
    }
]];

var table = json.map(items => {
  var tbody = items.map(item => `
    <tr>
      <td>${item.name}</td>
      <td>${item.class}</td>
    </tr>
  `).join('');
  return  `
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Class</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        ${tbody}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `;
}).join('');

var itemListTable = document.getElementById('itemListTable');
itemListTable.innerHTML = table;
```

```html
<div id="itemListTable">
</div>
```